# Entityframework 6.2.0 IQueryable.Count VS IQueryable.ToList().Count

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

This is a very weird problem
In short

```
var q = (some query).Count();
```

Gives my a number and

```
var q = (some query).ToList().Count();
```

Gives me entirely different number...

with mentioning that (some query) has two includes (joins)

is there a sane explanation for that???

**EDIT: here is my query**

```
var q = db.membership_renewals.Include(i => i.member).Include(i => i.sport).Where(w => w.isDeleted == false).Count();
```

this gives me a wrong number

and this:

```
var q = db.membership_renewals.Include(i => i.member).Include(i => i.sport).Where(w => w.isDeleted == false).ToList().Count();
```

Gives me accurate number..

**EDIT 2**
Wher I wrote my query as linq query it worked perfectly...

```
var q1 = (from d in db.membership_renewals where d.isDeleted == false join m in db.members on d.mr_memberId equals m.m_id join s in db.sports on d.mr_sportId equals s.s_id select d.mr_id).Count();
```

I think the problem that entity framework doesn't execute the joins in the original query but forced to execute them in (ToList())...

Comment: Without knowing more about the query, not much we can say

Comment: Write code examples so people can understand the problem and give you relevant answers.

Comment: OK I wrote my query code as an edit...

Answer (score 1):

I Finally figured out what's going on...
The database tables are not linked together in the database (there are no relationship or constraints defined in the database itself) so the code doesn't execute the (inner join) part.
However my classes on the other hand are well written so when I perform (ToList()) it automatically ignores the unbound rows...
And when I wrote the linq query defining the relation ship keys (primary and foreign) it worked alright because now the database understands my relation between tables...
Thanks everyone you've been great....

Answer (score 0):

My guess is IQueryable gives a smaller number cause not all the objects are loaded, kind of like a stream in Java, but IQueryable.toList().count() forces the Iqueryable to load all the data and it is traversed by the list constructor and stored in the list so IQueryable.toList().Count() is the accurate answer. This is based on 5 minutes of search on MSDN.

The idea is the underlying datastore of the IQueryable is a database iterator so it executes differently every time because it executes the query again on the database, so if you call it twice against the same table, and the data has changed you get different results. This is called delayed execution. But when you say IQueryable.ToList() you force the iterator to do the whole iteration once and dump the results in a list which is constant